PayPal REST API: Search by BUYER Transaction ID
I asked that already in PayPal community, but basically almost all questions there get no answers.
How can I use the PayPal REST API to search by BUYER Transaction ID? The only way I know is via the PayPal website, but I need a REST API solution. A search via
https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?fields=all&transaction_id=[ID]&start_date=[DATE]&end_date=[DATE]
is successfull with the SELLER transaction id, but fails with the BUYER transation id.
There is also a SO thread from 2011, which basically has the same question, but was not answered either.

There is no way to search by API using a buyer's transaction ID. It is not possible.
For an ID buyers and sellers can both see and reference, include an invoice_id parameter or similar when creating the transaction. Typically this field should contain the seller's own "order ID" and be unique for that account.
